# PWA in appstore installed under IOS keeps asking for Geolocation usage permission (does not remember permission)

Tags: ios, geolocation, progressive-web-apps

Good day,

I have a question regarding Geolocation and PWA.
Having build a fully working PWA that has gone through the process of validation and it is available in the APP store.

The APP features Geolocation and that also works.
Now the problem arises that the APP keeps asking for permission to use Geolocation (installed through the Apple Appstore) under IOS once in a while.

I have set the following option in the manifest.json file :

```
"permissions": [
    "geolocation"
],
```

So I "presume" I have done that one right...

What can I be missing?

I am requesting the GeoLocation through a very basic javascript code :

```
function updatePosition(latitude, longitude) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax/updateposition',
        data: {
            'latitude': latitude,
            'longitude': longitude
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('Position updated');
            console.log(response);
            if (response['success'] == true) {
                // Handle success response if needed
            }
        }
    });
}

function handleGeolocation(position) {
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log('User latitude = ' + latitude);
    console.log('User longitude = ' + longitude);
    updatePosition(latitude, longitude);
}

function handleGeolocationError(error) {
    console.error('Geolocation error:', error);
    // Handle geolocation error if needed
}

function requestGeolocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            handleGeolocation
            //, handleGeolocationError
        );
    } else {
        console.error('Geolocation is not supported by this browser');
        // Handle unsupported geolocation if needed
    }
}

requestGeolocation();
```

- note : I have commented out the "handleGeolocationError" method because it was requesting permission to use Geolocation three times in a row after installing. I have been looking like crazy to find a solution to that and I found someone that had the same thing when having the  error handling like I had. So I removed it. Since if it works. In a live environment for now it is not needed anyway.

Comment: Presumably your app is really just a web view running your PWA. If this is the case, then your PWA is treated no differently to a web site; it is the JavaScript in the web view that is requesting location permission, not your app.  It cannot be granted permanent location access via the request dialog.

Comment: Now probably a stupid question. How to change this? So how to make my my app does not behave like it is running in web view.

Comment: Write a "real" app. You can use react native if you want to stick with JavaScript/Typescript.

Comment: @Paulw11 Well I wrote a native app. But the client wanted a PWA because of the frequent updates and changes.

Comment: Unfortunately a PWA is not the same as a native app on iOS. Because changes are possible without going through app review, they are not trusted in the same way as a native app is. They are a web page.